# Weak $H^1$ convergence implies strong $L^p_{\text{loc}}$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

On page 210 of *Analysis* by by Elliott H. Lieb, Michael Loss (GSM 14), there is a theorem stating that if $f_j \to f$ weakly in $H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ then $\mathbf 1_A f_j \to \mathbf 1_A f$ strongly in $L^p(\mathbb R^n),$ where $A$ is any set with finite measure. Here $p<2^* := \frac{2n}{n-2}.$ So the injection $H^1 \to L^p_{\text{loc}}$ is continuous even if $H^1$ is equipped with weak topology.

In the proof below, it is shown by convolution mollification that $\|\mathbf 1_A (f_j-f)\|_{L^2} \to 0.$ But I cannot find a proof in the book that $\|\mathbf 1_A (f_j-f)\|_{L^p} \to 0.$

Here is my reasoning to fill in this gap:
since $f_j$ converges weakly in $H^1,$ it is uniformly bounded in norm in $H^1.$ Therefore, by Sobolev embedding, $f_j$ is uniformly bounded in norm in $L^q,$ for all $2\leq q \leq 2^*.$ Write $\|f_j\|_{L^q} \leq M_q.$ We have, by interpolation,
$$
\|\mathbf 1_A (f_j-f)\|_{L^p}  \lesssim \|\mathbf 1_A (f_j-f)\|_{L^2}^{\theta} \|\mathbf 1_A (f_j-f)\|_{L^q} ^{1-\theta}  \leq 2M_q^{1-\theta}\|\mathbf 1_A (f_j-f)\|_{L^2}^{\theta}.
$$
Hence $\mathbf 1_A f_j\to \mathbf 1_A  f$ in $L^p$ iff $\mathbf 1_A f_j \to \mathbf 1_A  f$ in $L^2.$

Is this the originally intended way to complete this proof?

Comment: Yes (to your final question).

Comment: You can also do it from the fact that in a space of finite measure, a family of functions uniformly bounded in $L^{1+\epsilon}$ is uniformly integrable.  This tells us that $1_A |f_j|^p$ are uniformly integrable, and it follows that they converge in $L^p$.